Can I drop and squash the same commit on two different branches with the same set of rebasing instructions?
I have a git status along the following lines
main-branch
* somehash001 (same as below)
* somehash002
...

feature-branch
* somehash003
* somehash001 (same as above)
...

I would like to rebase feature-branch onto main-branch so that the final state would be
feature-branch
* somehash004 (squash somehash001 and somehash003)
...

where the commit somehash004 is a squash of somehash001 and somehash003, I tried using git rebase --i main-branch to accomplish this, with rebasing instructions written as:
p somehash003 ...
s somehash001 ...

but my final state is
feature-branch
* somehash004 (correctly squashes somehash001 and somehash003)
* somehash001
...

I think this happens because somehash001 from feature-branch is squashed, but somehash001 from main-branch is kept
As I understand, I can't skip the commit from main-branch because it's the same as the commit I want to squash
I solved the issue with some ad-hoc resets, but my questions is: can I accomplish the state I described above from the given starting state with an interactive rebase? which instuctions should I use?

I think this question would be clearer if you used similar output to git log --graph --oneline. Perhaps put the top 2 examples into a single example so you can quickly see that feature-branch is just one commit ahead of main-branch. Also, when you rebase, you "rebase onto" (not "into") and you rewrite the checked out branch, so if you are rebasing feature-branch you would "Rebase feature-branch onto main-branch".

Note your ask may not be a good idea. Assuming main is a shared branch, it's bad practice to rewrite any commits of main. The end result you seek is squashing the one commit on the feature branch into the tip commit of the main branch. Later when you go to merge feature into main you'll have a new commit with duplicate content of a commit already on main plus additional stuff in it. So either you'll end up not accomplishing your goal of removing that commit, or, you would have to force-push main to remove it.

Continuing my previous comment of this perhaps not being a good idea, if this is a private repo and main isn't a shared branch with other people, then you can do whatever you want. Note that feature is already ahead of main so an interactive rebase on feature is all you need. Checkout feature and then git rebase HEAD~2 and squash the top two commits if you'd like.

I think you're right when you say I shouldn't touch a commit already present on main (assuming that will be public branch). On squashing the top 2 commits of feature, that's the whole point: one of the commits to squash is brought over from main and still present after the rebase

I just noticed your rebase commands might be flipped. I assume commit 1 would be at the top and is picked, and then commit 3 is under it and squashed. It's also not clear why commit 1 is still there after the rebase. If you actually squash commit 3 into commit 1, then commit 1 should no longer be in the history of the local branch you just rebased.

yeah that's what I would exepect to happen (and didn't), which is why I tried to make a general case and ask

my guess, is that the one commit from feature is squashed and the one from main is brought over intact as if picked. but I'm not that familiar with git that I know if the operation is intended to be performed in another way and I just encountered an edge case that isn't supposed to come up

I'm under the impression the git repository doesn't have an "issue" board  (https://github.com/git/git)

I don't think your "final state" example is possible if they are actually squashed. I suggest showing exact commands you ran with real commit IDs, and a before and after graph. Then we'll be able to help troubleshoot. (You may even be able to create a MRE with shell commands in a brand new repo from scratch so we can try it ourselves.)

at this point the original example was already solved long ago using some aggressive reverts...
